# How to remove Redirect Chain Error from my website

Tags: php, laravel, seo, cloudflare

Is anyone track what the exact error and what the reason this error come.
An error show Redirect Chain error on the MOZ Tool:

> http://example.com(301)
>
> https://example.com/(301)
>
> https://www.example.com/
>
> index-able URL show: https://example.com/

I used this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s//+(.*)\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s(.*/)/+\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=301,L]`
```

Comment: Please format your code properly

Answer (score -1):

In order to get rid of redirect chains you need to redirect the first URL to the last one in the group so that any redirection loops are eliminated.